# Non Associative Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hi I have come across many papers on non associative algebras which reference

A. A. Albert "On the power-associativity of rings, Summa Braziliensis Mathematicae vol. 2 (1948) pp. 21-33.",

but I cannot find it. Does anyone know of its whereabouts?

Many thanks

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere (although I did run across the [larger article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/69d7/31a56d9e2efa5ae375c90b6c9d7d207bb7d8.pdf) which you may already know about. At this point I'd fall back on an interlibrary loan program. This usually works (in the US public library system, anyhow.)

Comment: Hi yes I have the larger article, it was the counter examples I was after. Thanks for the help though.